# jquery plugins, how to send values connected to calling selector

Tags: jquery

I apologize for the confusion with the title, because it's a little difficult to describe.  If you have a better title, please let me know in the comments.

I'm using a sort of catch-all selector to call a jquery plugin (specifically the [maxlength plugin](http://keith-wood.name/maxlength.html)).

```
$("textarea[id^='description']").maxlength({max:500});
```

To note, one of the parameters you can send in is a jquery element for where you want feedback output to go.

These textareas are dynamically generated, and I have span tags that also dynamically generate as well.  The easiest way I could think of to tie them together was with a custom tag.  so each textarea is defined as:

```
<textarea id="descriptionX" tiedTo="feedbackX"></textarea>
```

and each span is defined as:

```
<span id="feedbackX"></span>
```

What I'm trying to do is send that textarea's "tiedTo" value as a jquery element to the function parameters.

Something like this:

```
$("textarea[id^='description']").maxlength(
    {
        max:500, 
        feedbackTarget: $('span[tiedTo="'+$(this).attr('tiedTo')+'"]')
    }
);
```

How can I send an attribute from a selector into a function like that?

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utWP8/) as well to sort of illustrate it further.  The More button just creates more textareas with random numbers in their id's.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you need => http://jsfiddle.net/utWP8/3/

you need to store the tiedTo in a variable:

```
var tiedToContainer=$("textarea[id^='areaText']").attr('tiedTo');
```

and then send it to the function:

```
$("textarea[id^='areaText']").maxlength({max:500, feedbackTarget: $('div[tiedTo=="'+tiedToContainer+'"]')});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/utWP8/22/)

Note: The documentation you linked to matches the plugin you're trying to use in your code. However, you included a completely different plugin in your fiddle. I've replaced it with the correct one in my fiddle.

You don't actually need a `tiedTo` attribute at all. If you create the element first and assign it to a variable, just use that variable when you call the maxlength plugin. However, I've left the variable in here in case you want to, say, remove them both later or something like that.

```
var tiedTo = 0;

function initTextarea() {
    var $desc = $('<div class="description" data-tiedTo="' + tiedTo + '"></div>');
    var $tarea = $('<textarea maxlength="500" class="areaText" data-tiedTo="' + tiedTo + '"></textarea>');
    $('#areas').append($desc).append($tarea).append('<br>');
    $tarea.maxlength({
        max: 500,
        feedbackTarget: $desc
    });
    tiedTo++;
}


$('#moreAreas').click(function () {
    initTextarea();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    initTextarea();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really have that much control over the text areas when they were generated, so I wasn't exactly able to make a variable every time they were created.  I was more focused on how to gain access to each text area, regardless of how they're generated.  I put the button in there for generating more of them because I needed something that would generate them.

Thank you Alex for pointing out the plugin problem on fiddle... I'm still a little fuzzy on how to import scripts on that page.

You both mentioned something about putting it in a variable, and that also seemed to get me closer to finding the answer.

However, I took at look at the [each selector function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and that gave me an idea.

```
$("textarea[id^='areaText']").each(function(index){
    var tiedTo = $(this).attr('tiedTo');
    var target = ('div[id="'+tiedTo+'"]');
    $(this).maxlength({max:500, feedbackTarget:target});
});
```

In this manner, I don't have to worry about what's generating the textareas, or where they're coming from... as long as I have that block above on page load, and on the click function of whatever button generates more of them.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utWP8/23/) has been updated to show final answer.

Thank you for all your help :)  It got me to the right answer.